# How to run a function while the ios app is running?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I want execute a function all time while my ios App is running.

What is the class where I need write this function, in the delegate?

I'm confused because if I declared this in viewContorller and change to other viewController this break. Or there is a function like

```
 func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
```

that this is running all time?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring specifically to didUpdateLocations, or any method in general?

Comment: A method in general that work like didUpdateLocations, all time and constantly

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring specifically to didUpdateLocations, this is a method that you don't call directly, but rather the OS calls to deliver location updates to you any time it receives them. While it's typically recommended that your location code is handled by some singleton somewhere to consolidate/encapsulate all the location logic, if you create a CLLocationManager and tell it to startUpdatingLocations, that method will be called constantly** by the OS without you having to deal with timers, loops etc.

** When the app is backgrounded the location updates will stop, and when the app comes back to the foreground the location updates will resume without you needing to restart them. These can come as often as once per second, but once again relies on the OS determining the location of the devices and delivering those updates to you.

If you're referring to anything else that is a different answer, but I suspect you're referring directly to location updates.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not referring to location updates. So what is the answer? Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends very strongly on what you want to do "all the time" or "constantly", and may very well be (in some cases) that you *shouldn't* do that.

Comment: For example I want to check memory/storage available in device and show to user when is low, I have the function to check storage but I don't know if I should use this in a thread..Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to put the function in another file, and use an NSThread

```
- (void)createThread
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startBackgroundJob) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)startBackgroundJob
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(monitorApp) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)monitorApp
{

}
```